# Trouble understanding recursion in this application

Tags: c++, recursion, indexing, sudoku, backtracking

I am writing a recursive solver for a Sudoku puzzle. I store blank places with 0's so that my program can read them more easily. I have the original puzzle stored starting from subscript one in order to better visualize the grid. I am not sure I have a full grasp on the recursion and that is where the problem is. I am getting output that seems like it is on track to solve the puzzle, but it is leaving zeros there that shouldn't be there. I think it has something to do with the placement of my unsetSquare, or with the return statements.

Here is a sample of the output...

```
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 5  6  8 
 2  6  8 | 0  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 5  6  9 
 2  6  8 | 0  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 5  6  0 
 2  6  8 | 1  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 5  6  0 
 2  6  8 | 2  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
**************************************************
 7  4  3 | 8  2  1 | 5  6  0 
 2  6  8 | 3  9  0 | 0  1  0 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  6 | 0  0  4 
---------|---------|---------
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 2  3  9 
 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 4  1  5 | 0  0  0 | 0  0  0 
---------|---------|---------
 9  0  0 | 5  0  0 | 0  0  0 
 0  2  0 | 0  1  0 | 7  4  0 
 0  0  0 | 2  0  0 | 9  0  5 
**************************************************
```

notice at the end of the first row, it goes to 8 looking for a solution, then to 9, 9 is not legal and it has reached the end of the for loop, so it replaces it with a zero and it continues. How can I make it go back to try different numbers in the first row to get a more complete solution?

Here is my recursion function...

```
bool DoTheWork::addSquare(int& depth, ostream& outStream){
    for(int i = ONE; i <= NINE; ++i){
        for(int j = ONE; j <= NINE; ++j){
            if(i == NINE && j == NINE && board.getSquare(NINE, NINE) != ZERO){
                cout << i << "     " << j << endl;
                return true;
            }
            //cout << "original" << board.getSquare(i, j) << "coord: " << i << ", " << j << endl;
            if(board.getSquare(i, j) == ZERO){
                //cout << "original: " << board.getSquare(i, j) << "coord: " << i << ", " << j << endl;
                for(int k = ONE; k <= NINE; ++k){
                    board.setSquare(i, j, k);
                    board.display(outStream);
                    if(board.isLegal()){
                         return addSquare(depth, outStream);  
                    }
                    else{
                        board.unsetSquare(i, j);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
    board.display(outStream);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: do you really think we debug the code for you? perhaps you can create a smaller case what shows the same problem.

Comment: This is as small as it gets. It is one function...like 15 lines of code.

Comment: You should remove the return true after addSquare(depth, outStream); and make it return addSquare(depth, outStream); instead. Although this will not fix your problem.

Comment: You are also not using depth at all. If you were to use that I would expect you to want to pass by value not reference.

Comment: Is that any different from what I have now, other than syntactically? I changed it, and you're right it didn't fix the problem, but I was wondering if the two ways to do it were equal?

Comment: Depth is only used for information to the user, to see how deep the recursion is going. I will add it into the function after I get it working.

Comment: My point about the return value is your current code throws away the value returned by recursion and replaces it with true. Although it may have to be true to be at that line of code anyways. I can not debug your code paths fully in my head..

Comment: Ok, I understand, it makes more sense to do it your way. Obviously I don't want to return things blindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had somethings in the wrong order, and not in the right scope. After successfully doing it with a while loop, I found the solution with a for loop.

```
bool DoTheWork::addSquare(int& depth, ostream& outStream){
    for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i){
        for(int j = 1; j < 10; ++j){
            if(board.getSquare(i, j) == 0){
                if(i == 10){
                    return true;
                }
                for(int k = 1; k <= 9; ++k){
                    board.setSquare(i, j, k);
                    if(board.isLegal() && addSquare(depth, outStream)){
                        return true;
                    }

                }
                board.unsetSquare(i, j);
                return false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a problem:

It should be:

```
if(board.isLegal()){
   if( addSquare(depth, outStream))
       return true;  
}
```

Means if the whole board is solved then roll back.

**EDIT** think about it:

you put 1 in the first square, it returns false. don't you want to try put 2?

**EDIT2**
More problem:

```
if(i == NINE && j == NINE && board.getSquare(NINE, NINE) != ZERO){
          cout << i << "     " << j << endl;
          return true;
}
```

Is this suppose to be a completion check? you check only 1 square. and in your sample it is filled!
you need to check that there is no 0.

**EDIT3:**

```
bool DoTheWork::addSquare(int& depth, ostream& outStream){
  //use flag to let you know if all completed
  bool zeroFound = false;
  for(int i = ONE; i <= NINE; ++i){
    for(int j = ONE; j <= NINE; ++j){
      //cout << "original" << board.getSquare(i, j) << "coord: " << i << ", " << j << endl;
      if(board.getSquare(i, j) == ZERO){
        zeroFound = true;
        //cout << "original: " << board.getSquare(i, j) << "coord: " << i << ", " << j << endl;
        for(int k = ONE; k <= NINE; ++k){
          board.setSquare(i, j, k);
          board.display(outStream);
          if(board.isLegal()){
            if(addSquare(depth, outStream)){
              return true;  
            }
            else{
              board.unsetSquare(i, j);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
  board.display(outStream);
  return !zeroFound; //true in case it is full!
}
```

Comment: I tried it, and it didn't solve the problem. I believe that is the same answer @drescherjm offered, but with different syntax.

Comment: in case of false, you don't want to return, you want to move to next value.

Comment: Oh, I see, however it still does not get rid of the lingering zeros in the output.

Comment: Just saw your edit, I am already doing that with my current code, it tires all the numbers from 1 to 9. I am not sure what you're suggesting, how is that any different from what I am already doing? Excuse me if it is obvious, new to this.

Comment: The last edit is stuck in a infinite loop, that is what seems to happen for almost every solution I come up with.

Comment: are u sure it is infinite? it looks like very long recursion. for each empty square you check 9 options: your complexity is: (empty squares) power 9. and take again the code I fix some mismatch {}

Comment: Positive, I stop it after about 45 seconds, and look at the output, and it is leaving the same zeros.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40225/discussion-between-shr-and-trevor-hutto)